# Displaying caption of an image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, caption

I am trying to make images with captions, and when it is clicked, caption should appeared using jquery.
I have 2 problems.
First problem is that second caption is visible even if i used jquery to hide it.
Second problem is that i want to display only caption of image u are "clicking", not all captions.
U can find my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/S279z/)**
I hope u have any ideas or suggestion for my problem.Thanks!!
**HTML**

```
<div id="galerija_album">
        <div id="galerija_slika"><a href="#"><img src="http://web.enavu.com/demos/cssCaption/wolf.jpg"/ ></a></div>
        <span>Hello<li id="galerija_informacije_show"><img src="slike/arrow_down.png"/ ></li><br>
          <li id="galerija_informacije">Some text</li>
        </span>
       </div>
            <div id="galerija_album">
        <div id="galerija_slika"><a href="#"><img src="http://web.enavu.com/demos/cssCaption/wolf.jpg"/ ></a></div>
        <span>Hello<li id="galerija_informacije_show"><img src="slike/arrow_down.png"/ ></li><br>
          <li id="galerija_informacije">Some text</li>
        </span>
       </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#galerija_album{
    margin:20px;
    width:195px;
    height:150px;
    padding:7px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:15px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    background:white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#galerija_album img{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;

}
#galerija_slika{


}
#galerija_album span{
    position:absolute; 
    margin:5px;
    bottom:2px; 
    left:2px;
    width:175px;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: 'verdana';
    font-size:15px;
    color:lightblue;
    opacity:0.7; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); 
    padding:10px;

}
#galerija_informacije_show{
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
#galerija_informacije_show:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#galerija_informacije{
    list-style: none;

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#galerija_informacije").hide();
    $("#galerija_informacije_show").click(function(){
        $("#galerija_informacije").slideToggle("fast");

    });

});
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Use classes instead in you need to repeat.

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid. You can't use an `li` without a `ul` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the JSFiddle provided, I've updated it with the changes needed to

1. Display the captions only when the image is clicked
2. Expand the further information when the drop down image is clicked

My updates are available at http://jsfiddle.net/S279z/2/

I've provided a function which hides all of the captions.  Then there are the on click events, the first is applied to the image of the dogs, which when clicked will show the caption.  The second on click event is on the drop down, which will expand the further information in the div class galerija_informacije.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hideAll = function() {
        $("span.galerija_informacije_show").hide();
        $(".galerija_informacije").hide();
    };
    hideAll();

    $('.galerija_album').on('click', function() {
        hideAll();
        $("span.galerija_informacije_show", this).slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('.galerija_informacije_show').on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.galerija_informacije_show img').on('click', function() {
        console.log(this.parentNode);
        $(".galerija_informacije", this.parentNode).slideToggle("fast");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

I've updated the HTML to have IDs, and also to remove the list items, and instead use divs where I need them

**HTML**

```
<div id="galerija_album_0" class="galerija_album">
    <div id="galerija_slika"><a href="#"><img src="http://web.enavu.com/demos/cssCaption/wolf.jpg"/ ></a>

     <span id="galerija_informacije_show_0" class="galerija_informacije_show">Hello<img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120818025551/merlin1/images/4/46/Drop_down_arrow.gif"/ ><br>
          <div id="galerija_informacije_0" class="galerija_informacije">Some text</div>
        </span>
         </div>

</div>
<div id="galerija_album_1" class="galerija_album">
    <div id="galerija_slika"><a href="#"><img src="http://web.enavu.com/demos/cssCaption/wolf.jpg"/></a>

    <span id="galerija_informacije_show_1" class="galerija_informacije_show">Hello<img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120818025551/merlin1/images/4/46/Drop_down_arrow.gif"/ ><br>
        <div id="galerija_informacije_1" class="galerija_informacije">Some text</div>
        </span>
        </div> 

</div>
```

For the CSS, there are some changes to make sure that it still looks like the example you provided

**CSS**

```
.galerija_album{
    margin:20px;
    width:195px;
    height:150px;
    padding:7px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:15px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    background:white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galerija_album span{
    position:absolute; 
    margin:5px;
    bottom:2px; 
    left:2px;
    width:175px;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: 'verdana';
    font-size:15px;
    color:lightblue;
    opacity:0.7; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); 
    padding:10px;

}
.galerija_album div a img{
    width: 100%;

}
.galerija_informacije_show img{
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.galerija_informacije_show{
    cursor: auto;
}
```